# "Worse for wear and tear" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the lyrics of the song "Far Away Eyes" by the Rolling Stones it is said:

*I had an arrangement to meet a girl, and I was kind of late

And I thought by the time I got there she'd be off

She'd be off with the nearest truck driver she could find

Much to my surprise, there she was sittin' in the corner

A little bleary, worse for wear and tear

Was a girl with far away eyes*

I researched the meaning of the expression "worse for wear and tear" and found the following:

*Origin of Worse for Wear

This translates into as things are used, they wear and deteriorate. After worse for wear became a popular expression, a new expression came about: none worse for the wear, meaning used but not worn out. Similar expressions to worse for wear are worn out and wear and tear.*

I can't understand how this type of adjective applies to a person, in this case the girl mentioned in the song. As far as I can understand it seems to be appropriate if you're talking about clothes, shoes, etc., but I can't decipher what it could mean in relation to a person.

In fact the entire phrase "*A little bleary, worse for wear and tear*" sounds confusing or unclear to me, including what the actual meaning of the expression "a little bleary" could be.

Comment: I don't remember hearing this expression without an initial "the": "Looking much _**the** worse for wear_." Collins, Oxford, Cambridge and Longman dictionaries seem to confirm that usage. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much+worse+for+wear%2Cmuch+the+worse+for+wear&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=4) too.

Comment: Where does your quote come from? You are supposed to reference such things. Was it ChatGPT? ([Cambridge Dictionaries](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-worse-for-wear) give a good answer so you should maybe look there next time.)

Comment: Did you look up **bleary** in a dictionary?

Comment: The speaker of the lyric imagines her to be living a difficult life of some kind. She could be a runaway teen. We gather from the lyric  *I thought by the time I got there ...
She'd be off with the nearest truck driver she could find* it's possible she was being used, possibly roughly, by strangers. She would be worse from that kind of physical and emotional "wear and tear". Her eyes could be bleary from fatigue, poor nutrition, drinking, or drug-use, or all of those things combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of that verse suggests that the girl could be a party girl or a working girl.  Either way, such activities take a toll, physical and emotional, looking old beyond her years.

Meaning, she is suffering the wear and tear of her lifestyle.

Now, it is an odd construct and is actually a combination of two expressions.

"worse for wear" something showing it's usage.  "That saddle's a bit worse for wear but still good."

and

"wear and tear" the actual usage put on something.  "Taking the train saves wear and tear on your car."

Both expressions are very old so I'll say it's just poetic license.

"A little bleary" (dull, unfocused, tired) suggests she may have just returned from an encounter with an aforementioned truck driver.  Looking disheveled and unkept as a result.

Comment: None  of "bleary-eyed", "worse for wear", or "wear and tear" are archaic.  They're all in common, current use.

Comment: @BadZen Just stop.  I did not say they were _archaic_ in any way, show me the quote.  I said they are very old, which they are, so it's unlikely Mick or Keith weren't already familiar with them.

Comment: “Bleary” suggests she’s been drinking (appropriate for a bar), rather than the other thing that ends in “ing” with the truck driver. That could be the source of her being “worse for wear and tear”.

Answer (score 1):

"Bleary" here has the sense of "bleary-eyed", as in "weary or tired".  MW additionally gives "unfocused or filmy".   You probably have experienced "bleary eyes", late at night or early in the morning.

"Worse for wear" means the thing we are describing is damaged or in some other way undesirable because of age or constant use.   Think of tires wearing down over time, or leather shoes starting to fall apart.  The phrases "worse for wear" and "wear and tear" are here combined, with roughly the same meaning as "worse for wear".

This expression can absolutely apply to a person - the implication is that their life experience has been difficult or in some way damaging and has left them worse off.

The entire expression "A little bleary, worse for wear and tear" has the same meaning as "a little bleary-eyed, *and* worse for wear and tear".

Comment: Saying someone is '[the] worse for wear' is a very common informal way of saying that they are drunk.